# Huge process time differences depending on slight query paremeters difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models, PartMaster and Location, with a one to many relationship. I have to perform a search on the field part_masters.combo and locations.ubicacion, by using left join of the two tables.

My problem is that the same query process time is absolutely different depending on how the parameters of the query are.

This query has an execution time of around **450 ms**.

The plan for the query is this

[plan for the query looking for 'P0'](http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/plan_1527591568019)

```
SELECT DISTINCT "part_masters".* FROM "part_masters" LEFT OUTER JOIN 
"locations" ON "locations"."sap_cod" = "part_masters"."sap_cod" WHERE 
(unaccent(locations.ubicacion) ILIKE unaccent('%P0%')) AND 
(unaccent(part_masters.combo) ILIKE unaccent('%junta%')) AND 
(unaccent(part_masters.combo) ILIKE unaccent('%torica%')) ORDER BY 
"part_masters"."sap_cod" ASC
```

And this other query, just changing 'P0' for 'P01'as query parameter of locations.ubicacion takes **38 secs** to get executed, i got outtimed most of the time.

[plan for the query looking for 'P01'](http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/plan_1527591500155)

```
SELECT DISTINCT "part_masters".* FROM "part_masters" LEFT OUTER JOIN 
"locations" ON "locations"."sap_cod" = "part_masters"."sap_cod" WHERE 
(unaccent(locations.ubicacion) ILIKE unaccent('%P01%')) AND 
(unaccent(part_masters.combo) ILIKE unaccent('%junta%')) AND 
(unaccent(part_masters.combo) ILIKE unaccent('%torica%')) ORDER BY 
"part_masters"."sap_cod" ASC
```

ANALYZE OUTPUT:

```
Unique  (cost=3880.72..3880.77 rows=1 width=242) (actual 
time=39902.298..39902.305 rows=8 loops=1)
->  Sort  (cost=3880.72..3880.73 rows=1 width=242) (actual 
time=39902.297..39902.297 rows=8 loops=1)
    Sort Key: part_masters.sap_cod, part_masters.id, 
part_masters.descripcion_maestro, part_masters.ref_fabricante, 
part_masters.fabricante, part_masters.stock, part_masters.precio_medio, 
part_masters.planta_cod, part_masters.planta_nombre, 
part_masters.unidad_medida, part_masters.grupo_compras, 
part_masters.created_at, part_masters.updated_at, 
part_masters.combinada_maestro, part_masters.precio_estandar, 
part_masters.fabricante_nombre, part_masters.combo
    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..3880.71 rows=1 width=242) (actual 
time=10393.015..39902.250 rows=8 loops=1)
          Join Filter: ((part_masters.sap_cod)::text = 
(locations.sap_cod)::text)
          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 438318
          ->  Seq Scan on part_masters  (cost=0.00..2451.75 rows=1 
 width=242) (actual time=2.135..315.211 rows=262 loops=1)
                Filter: ((unaccent(combo) ~~* unaccent('%junta%'::text)) AND 
 (unaccent(combo) ~~* unaccent('%torica%'::text)))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 38408
          ->  Seq Scan on locations  (cost=0.00..1409.24 rows=1578 width=5) 
 (actual time=0.107..148.671 rows=1673 loops=262)
                Filter: (unaccent((ubicacion)::text) ~~* 
 unaccent('%P01%'::text))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 37586
 Total runtime: 39902.358 ms
```

I have this index in combo, is not being used.

part_masters_on_combo_idx UNUSED (trigram index)

There isn't any index for locations.ubicacion.

According to the plans I linked, there is a huge difference in both Actual Loops and Shared Hit Blocks number, I don't know if that helps

Comment: Please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output to the question.

Comment: Post edited with explain analyze

Comment: According to the plans I linked in the posts, there is a huge difference in both Actual Loops and Shared Hit Blocks number, I don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need indexes so that PostgreSQL can speed up the query and calculate better estimates:

```
CREATE INDEX ON part_masters (lower(unaccent(combo)) text_pattern_ops);
CREATE INDEX ON locations (lower(unaccent(ubicacion)) text_pattern_ops);
```

Then run `ANALYZE` on both tables.

In addition, you will have to rewrite the three conditions:

```
unaccent(part_masters.combo) ILIKE unaccent('%junta%')
```

like this:

```
lower(unaccent(part_masters.combo)) LIKE lower(unaccent('%junta%'))
```

That should get you significant performance gains.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz, I will try your suggestions. Did you have the chance to take a look on the plan stats I posted? I find really weird the difference in Actual Loops and Shared hit Block Numbers.

Comment: I don't see the shared hit block numbers, but I saw the misestimate. I hinted at it in my answer, and I believe that the indexes will improve it.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback, I was implementing your suggestions but I'm getting this error creating the new indexes: `PG::InvalidObjectDefinition: ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`

Comment: True. If you never plan to modify the `unaccent` dictionary, you can cheat by creating an `IMMUTABLE` function: `CREATE FUNCTION my_unaccent(text) LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE AS 'SELECT unaccent($1)';` and using that function instead.

Comment: Getting this error now: `PG::InvalidFunctionDefinition: ERROR:  function result type must be specified`.EDIT solved adding RETURNS text to the definition

Comment: Sorry, I just typed it without actually testing.

Comment: No problem Laurenz, appreciate your help very much. I'm gonna try how everything works with the new index and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Well, it has definitely improve the performance of the query. As shown here, it is using the new index in part_masters (not the one in locations) http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/plan_1528294838267. However, this very same index is not being used if the only query parameter is for part_masters.combo, Therefore, the perfomance is worse querying on one table and one parameter than querying for a join table and adding another query paraneter from the join table. Weird.